# Rails 5: Not showing exception page in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have just updated my Rails app from 4.3 to 5.0. Currently however, it is not showing the exception page. Instead, it is showing the error as a JSON response. Checking my `config/application.rb`, I did set the `config.api_only = false`.

[image: Stacktrace]

Comment: how's your application controller defined? what it inherits from? and just to be sure, you restarted the app, right?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Inherit from just a normal ActionController::Base. It works fine before this. I'm only getting this page after I've upgraded to Rails 5.0, so I thought it could be because of that